# Hot to Create multiple list data in one drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC4. and I have any Question.

I use DropDownListFor() to create DropDownList

Example : I use this Code in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.createAccount.AccountId, Model.AccountNameListData)
```

AccountNameListData in Model

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountNameListData { get; set; }
```

and This is My Example DropDownList(Following This Picture)

[image]

***Question***

IF I Have List Data Following This Code in Model

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountNumberListData { get; set; }
```

Example : this value keep data as {001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006}

When I Click At DropDownList I want to see

```
001 - Pretty Casg
002 - Exchange
003 - Pretty Cash
004 - I/O Ex
005 - Petty Cash
006 - Hello World
```

- How to make its with DropDownList or Did You have other way Please Tell me T^T
- now I tried that

Ex  New Define `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> keepValue {get; set;}` in Model
    in view Model.KeepValue = Model.AccountNumberListData - Model.AccountNameListData

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.createAccount.AccountId,Model.KeepValue )
```

But it's not work.

Please Help me T^T

Answer (score 0):

```
[AcceptVerbs(Http.Get)]
public ActionResult GetValueExample() {
  ViewData["MyItems"] = GetSelectList();
  return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(Http.Get)]
public ActionResult GetValueExample(string MyList) {
  //MyList contains the selected value
  SelectList list = GetSelectList(); //list will contain the original list of items
  //...
}

private SelectList GetSelectList() {
  Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  list.Add("Item 1", "1");
  list.Add("Item 2", "2");
  list.Add("Item 3", "3");
  return new SelectList(list, "value", "key");
}

//...

<%= Html.DropDownList("MyList", ViewData["MyItems"] as SelectList) %>
```